# How to use git with pipenv?

Tags: git, pipenv

1. On my main system, I already have the git dpkg installed.

   ```
   $ dpkg -l | grep git
   ii  git                                        1:2.25.1-1~ppa0~ubuntu18.04.1                    amd64        fast, scalable, distributed revision control system
   ii  git-man                                    1:2.25.1-1~ppa0~ubuntu18.04.1                    all          fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (manual pages)
   ```

   Do I still do a `pipenv install git` to use git while inside the pipenv shell? I did try to install git in the directory having a pipenv shell. Although it wrote success, there were other warnings and errors.

   ```
   $ pipenv install git
   Installing git…
   Adding git to Pipfile's [packages]…
   ✔ Installation Succeeded 
   Pipfile.lock (427769) out of date, updating to (affaee)…
   Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
   Locking [packages] dependencies…
   ✘ Locking Failed! 
   [pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 69, in resolve
   [pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=requirements_dir
   [pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 726, in resolve_deps
   [pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=req_dir,
   [pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 480, in actually_resolve_deps
   [pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       resolved_tree = resolver.resolve()
   [pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 395, in resolve
   [pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
   [pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure: ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches git
   [pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       No versions found
   [pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
     First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again.
    Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
     Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
   ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches git
   No versions found
   Was https://pypi.org/simple reachable?
   [pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=requirements_dir
   [pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 726, in resolve_deps
   [pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=req_dir,
   [pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 480, in actually_resolve_deps
   [pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       resolved_tree = resolver.resolve()
   [pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:   File "~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 395, in resolve
   [pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
   [pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure: ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches git
   [pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]:       No versions found
   [pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
     First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again.
    Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
     Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
   ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches git
   No versions found
   Was https://pypi.org/simple reachable?
   ```
2. Do I run git while inside a pipenv shell or outside of it?

Comment: `dpkg` lists system packages; you have a system `git`, good. `pipenv` (like any Python package manager — `pip` or any other) installs **only** Python packages. `pipenv install git` installs… well, I think it's [GitPython](https://pypi.org/project/GitPython/) — a Python wrapper for `git` that runs `git` behind the scene.

Comment: @phd, I think the question was rather how to get sources (preferable in a form of Git repository) of any of the `pipenv` provided packages. Otherwise, yes, GitPython is what usually one may get.

Comment: @0andriy I don't think so. "*Do I still do a pipenv install git to use git…?*" IMO that means confusion between `git` and GitPython.

Comment: @phd @0andrly I am unclear about how to use `git` when I am using a `pipenv shell`. Do I need to install `git` again to use git when in a `pipenv shell`? Or do I need to exit `pipenv shell` to submit `git` commands?

Comment: I know nothing about `pipenv` ([it's dead](https://medium.com/telnyx-engineering/rip-pipenv-tried-too-hard-do-what-you-need-with-pip-tools-d500edc161d4) anyway). Does `pipenv shell` provide OS shell or Python command line?

Comment: @phd Thanks It provides an OS shell. I found this issue [If this project is dead, just tell us ](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4058)

Comment: In an OS shell you don't need `pipenv install git` because `pipenv install` installs a Python package which you not gonna use. Just use system `git`.

Answer (score 7):

It isn't required to install `git` in your `pipenv`. You would just have the git repo in the directory. That directory would have your `pipenv`.

Run `git` outside the `pipenv` shell. The shell is to manage your environment but git controls the directory where your source code is maintained.

Comment: @Sun Bear Shouldn't this be the approved as the answer? Clearly installing `git` in your `pipenv` isn't  the way to go. I'd like to point out that you can run `git` commands while you are in your `pipenv` shell. So it isn't necessarily a horrible approach.